# D3 hover chart - thousands of x entries - mouse sensitivity

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have created the following charts using D3 :
[image: chart]
<sub>(source: [envhealthatlas.co.uk](http://envhealthatlas.co.uk/bow_tie_like_chart.png))</sub>

This is to visualize the distribution of the 3 variables in ascent order and identify values below and greater than 1.

The vertical bar synchronize the 3 charts and moves accordingly when the mouse is hovered. The mousemove function in the code below gets the x value corresponding for the specific mouse coords and then from a lookup I can get the identifier which allows me to sync the bar movement with all 3 charts.

```
 var xS = d3.scale.linear()
  .range( [ 0, this.width ] )//width 400
  .domain( [1,  options.data.length]); 

var yS = d3.scale.linear()
  .range( [ this.height, 0 ] )
  .domain( [ 0, this.maxDataPoint ] );


var linename =  this.name + "_line";


this.area = d3.svg.area()
  //.interpolate( "monotone" )
  .x( function( d ) {
    return xS( +d[xOrder] );
  } )
  .y0( function( d ) {
    if ( d[ localName ] < 1 ) {
      return yS( d[ localName ] );
    } else {
      return yS( 1 )
    }

  } )
  .y1( function( d ) {
    if ( d[ localName ] < 1 ) {
      return yS( 1 );
    } else {
      return yS( d[ localName ] )
    }
  } );


this.chartContainer = svg.append( "g" )
  .attr( 'class', this.name.toLowerCase() )
  .attr( "transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + ( this.margin.top + ( this.height * this.id ) + ( 10 * this.id ) ) + ")" );

/* We've created everything, let's actually add it to the page */
this.chartContainer.append( "path" )
  .data( [ options.data ] )
  .attr( "class", "chart unadj " + this.name.toLowerCase() )
  .attr( "clip-path", "url(#clip-" + this.id + ")" )
  .attr( "d", this.area );


var mousemove = function( d ) {

    var xValue = Math.round(xS.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0])) ,
        gid = null;

    var update = function( xVal , txt, set ){
        lines[set]
          .attr("transform","translate(" + xS(xVal) + "," + 0 + ")");
        texts[set]
          .text( txt );
    };

    if( typeof dataSets[localName][xValue] !== 'undefined'){
        gid =  dataSets[localName][xValue]["gid"];// Sync with other area charts
    };      

    for (var set in dataSets){ 
        var dataLength = dataSets[set].length ;
        while(dataLength--){
            if(dataSets[set][dataLength]["gid"] === gid){
                var xVal =  +dataSets[set][dataLength][xOrder],// xOrder is an auto increment field used for sync purpose and for the xs linear scale
                    yVal = dataSets[set][dataLength][set];
                update(xVal, yVal, set);  
            };      
        };
    };  
};

this.chartContainer.append( "rect" )
    .attr( "class", "overlayHover" )
    .attr( "width", width)
    .attr( "height", chartHeight )
    .on( "mousemove", mousemove );

/* Highlighter */
lines[localName] = this.chartContainer.append("line")
    .attr("class", "lineHover")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", chartHeight)
    .attr("height", 2 )
    .attr("height", chartHeight )
    .attr("id", linename );


this.yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale( yS ).orient( "left" ).tickValues( [ 0, 1, this.maxDataPoint ]);

this.chartContainer.append( "g" )
  .attr( "class", "y axis" )
  .attr( "transform", "translate(0,0)" )
  .call( this.yAxis );

this.chartContainer.append( "text" )
  .attr( "class", "country-title" )
  .attr( "transform", "translate(10,20)" )
  .text( this.name  );

texts[localName] = this.chartContainer.append( "text" )
  .attr( "class","areaValue")
  .attr ( "id", localName + "_text"  )
  .attr( "transform", "translate(10,32)" )
  .text("0.00");    

};
```

THE ISSUE:
The charts seem to be behaving well however, by using my current data set with a few thousand records I realized that some values are never displayed. For example if I hover to the very left or very right of the charts (at its lowest or highest) I cannot  get the mouse coordinates to go to 0.00 and 400 (chart width) and therefore cannot get the extremes of my dataset.

Is there an issue with the width available and the number of x entries?

Data looks as follows I have about 9000 records:

```
gid,rr_unadj,x_order
948,0.751,1
947,0.751,2
6728,0.762,3
950,0.768,4
```

Any help appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the 0 and 400 points, by being so close to the edge, are essentially fall outside the rect used for capturing mousemove events and/or are outside the SVG altogether. And if so, you'll need to make the rect slightly wider, so that it can capture x coords that are < 0 or > 400 (and then Math.min/Math.max the value to keep it within 0 to 400). And, because the SVG boundaries clip the rect, you'll also need to increase the SVG's width to introduce some padding around it.

Comment: The biggest problem is the limited width available. If my X is 400px wide but I have 8800 entries and the line doing the mouse hover effect can only move 1px at the time how can it move across the  the whole data set if xS.invert(mouseX) can only have 400 unique mouseX coordinate values

Answer (score 0):

Right, that's a problem with mouse resolution, primarily. But even with an infinitely sensitive mouse, you wouldn't expect a human user to be able to control the mouse so precisely. With my mouse, moving 400 pixels on screen equals about 7cm on the mousepad (= 70mm). With 8800 points, that's about 125 data points per millimeter. Too much. So you have to come up with an alternate way to interact with the chart, and it's going to involve more work.

The simplest option I can think of is to listen to mousemove events on the document instead of the rect:

```
d3.select(document) // Maybe "body" is better than document
  ...
  .on("mousemove", mousemove)
```

Then you'll get mouse values across the entire window. Then you'd need to define the range of `xS` as

```
xS.range([0, window.innerWidth])
```

This way, depending on the browser window size, you can get up to 4 times the resolution. Obviously the mouse position wouldn't correspond to the highlighted position on the chart, but that's not necessarily a problem. What *is* a problem is that with 8800 records, it still wouldn't be enough mouse resolution for the precision you're demanding. (NOTE: I just realized that with this scheme you'd also need to take mouse y-position into account, determining which chart is vertically aligned to it.)

Another approach is to use the arrow keys or the mouse scroll wheel to move from one record to the one immediately after or before it. In this scenario, you'd first read the mouse position, just like you currently do, to lookup the whichever record it yields. But then, as long as the mouse is kept still, the user can refine that position using the scroll wheel or keys. Your `gid` lookup would look like this:

```
gid =  dataSets[localName][xValue + refinement]
```

`refinement` would be initialized to 0, but each time the up or down is pressed, you'd increment/decrement it by 1.

Comment: Great advices and comments! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I will try the arrow keys approach !

Answer (score 0):

As per suggested I have implemented the keyboard approach which allows to go through each entry in the X axis, code can be found here:
https://github.com/smallAreaHealthStatisticsUnit/rapidInquiryFacility/blob/master/rifWebPlatform/web/js/v2/components/chart/units/d3renderers/multipleAreaCharts.d3renderer.js

It works nicely.

Integrated in the disease mapping platform below:
[image: disease mapping]
<sub>(source: [envhealthatlas.co.uk](http://www.envhealthatlas.co.uk/disease_mapping.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks again to meetamit for his sharp advices (see below)!